# Converting only one column into int from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, integer

I have a list of lists. For example a sample_list

```
[['11', 'A', '23.45'], [['15', 'B', '11.63'], ['53', 'C', '62.78']]
```

I want to convert only the third column into the int. so the output looks something like:

```
[['11', 'A', 23.45], [['15', 'B', 11.63], ['53', 'C', 62.78]]
```

I tried doing a bunch of things including:

```
for item in sample_list:
    item[2] = int(item[2])
```

But no matter what I do, I keep getting an error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23.45'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but i am not allowed to use any libraries like pandas or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `23.45` is not an integer. Try

```
item[2] = int(float(item[2]))
```

This will first convert the string to a `float`, then `float` to an `int`.

Comment: I am so dumb. I realized it after I posted it. I don't know what I was thinking posting this